# How do I preserve the setuid bit in tar archives with Perl's Archive::Tar?

Tags: perl, tar, setuid

I'm using Perl's [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Tar) module. It preserves the file permissions but doesn't preserve the sticky bit. At the other end where I extract the archive, all the sticky bits are gone. I think UNIX/LINUX operating system stores these sticky bits somewhere else. How can I make my archive preserve sticky bits also?

Using the -p switch to tar  preserves it but how do I do it using [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Tar)? I'm using Perl's module on both the sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Fine Source, Archive::Tar::File strips off the high bits from the mode.
You can try the following magic incantation at the beginning of your script (before anything
might have referenced Archive::Tar) and see if that subverts it:

```
use Archive::Tar::Constant ();
BEGIN {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub{};
    *Archive::Tar::Constant::STRIP_MODE = sub(){ sub {shift} };
}
...
use Archive::Tar;
...
```

Brief explanation: STRIP_MODE is a constant that contains a subroutine that can be passed the raw mode and returns the mode that should be stored.  It is normally set to

```
sub { shift() & 0777 }
```

Because it is a constant, imported from Archive::Tar::Constant into Archive::Tar::File and used there, whatever it is set to will be inlined into Archive::Tar::File as it is compiled.  So to change it, the constant must be changed before it is inlined, that is, before Archive::Tar::File ever gets loaded.

N.B. Because changing an inlinable constant is prone to error (changing it after it is too late to have any effect), it normally generates a severe warning that can't be disabled by usual means.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but on the official tar command, you need to pass *-p* to make this happen

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the [Archive::Tar documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Tar) for the details.  From a brief glance, it appears that

```
$Archive::Tar::CHMOD = 1;
```

should do what you want, although the documentation claims that the above setting is the default.  It may be that Archive::Tar strips off the higher-order mode bits like the sticky bit.

Is the archive both created and extracted with Archive::Tar, or are you using the standard tar program at one end or the other?